# p5.js loadPixels() with user upload returning array of all zeros

Tags: javascript, p5.js

An application I am writing requires a user to upload an image. After the image is uploaded, I'd like to get an array of all the pixels.

The following code achieves this, however, **the first image uploaded always returns an array of zeros**.

```
let img; 
let input; 


function setup() { 
  input = createFileInput(handleFile); 
  input.position(0, 0); 
} 


function draw() { 
  if (img) { 
    image(img, 0, 0, width, height); 
  } 
} 

imageCallback = (img) => {
  let c = get();
  console.log(pixels);
}

function handleFile(file) { 
  if (file.type === 'image') { 
    img = createImg(file.data, imageCallback);   
    img.hide(); 
  } 

}
```

Image upload results (the second image will always have a populated pixel array):

[image]

I received this error before adding the `imageCallback` function, and hoped that would solve the issue. It didn't, so I'm here now.

Any help is appreciated!

**Edit: Working Solution**

As @KevinWorkman pointed out below, I didn't yet write the image to canvas.

I rewrote the code so that the callback ensured the image was loaded *and written to the canvas* before running `get()`.

```
let input; 

function setup() { 
  input = createFileInput(handleFile); 
  input.position(0, 0); 
} 


function handleFile(file) { 
  if (file.type === 'image') { 
    loadImage(file.data, img => {
      image(img, 0, 0, width/2, height);
      get();
      console.log(pixels)
    });   
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this line:

```
let c = get();
```

Notice that this is calling the general `get()` function, which returns the pixel array of the canvas. Also note that at this point, you haven't drawn the image to the canvas yet. That's why this is all zeroes at this point.

Then you do draw the image to the canvas using this line:

```
image(img, 0, 0, width, height);
```

Now if you upload a new image, you run that first line again, which returns the pixel array of the canvas. At this point, the canvas will still be showing the previously loaded image! This is not the pixel array of the newly loaded image!

You probably want the `p5.Image.get()` function instead of the general `get()` function. You can find more info in [the reference](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Image/get).

Comment: Hey Kevin, forgive my confusion - I was under the impression that running `get()` inside the callback would only resolve *after* the image was loaded.Without using a callback (or some sort of promise), how can I ensure that my code runs only after the execution? I'll experiment with using `p5.Image.get()`, but I'd like to understand this behavior, as it's my main source of confusion. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @JaredWilber The image is indeed loaded, but the `get()` function doesn't reference the image at all. It's referencing the canvas, and nothing has been drawn to the canvas when you call this. To experiment, try drawing something to the canvas, like draw a red circle to the canvas inside the `setup()` function, and you'll see that reflected in the pixel array that you're printing out.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I edited the question with my solution. I couldn't get `p5.Image.get()` to work correctly for some reason (it only seemed to yield empty arrays where it worked), but `get()` works as intended in my solution.

Comment: @JaredWilber Also note that `p5.Image` has a `pixel` field that you can probably use directly: https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Image/pixels